# How can show error icon on eclipse editor tab

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I add a marker from type error in the problems view and as expected the line was underlined and annotated with an error and on the project explorer view the error icon was displayed.
But I expect the error icon also in the tab section, marked as yellow in the screenshot below.

Custom editor:
[image: Custom Editor]

```xml
   <extension
id="myproject.ui.error"
name="Audit Marker"
point="org.eclipse.core.resources.markers">
<super type="org.eclipse.core.resources.problemmarker"/>
<super type="org.eclipse.core.resources.textmarker"/>
<persistent value="true"/>
<attribute name="key"/>
<attribute name="violation"/>
</extension>

<extension
point="org.eclipse.ui.editors.markerAnnotationSpecification">
<specification
annotationType="myproject.ui.error"
colorPreferenceKey="squiggles.color"
colorPreferenceValue="253,255,157"
highlightPreferenceKey="squiggles.background"
highlightPreferenceValue="false"
includeOnPreferencePage="false"
label="ErrorSpecification"
overviewRulerPreferenceKey="squiggles.rulers.overview"
overviewRulerPreferenceValue="true"
presentationLayer="4"
textPreferenceKey="squiggles.text"
textPreferenceValue="true"
textStylePreferenceKey="squiggles.text.style"
textStylePreferenceValue="UNDERLINE"
verticalRulerPreferenceKey="squiggles.rulers.vertical"
verticalRulerPreferenceValue="true"/>
</extension>

<extension
point="org.eclipse.ui.editors.annotationTypes">
<type
markerSeverity="2"
markerType="myproject.ui.error"
name="myproject.ui.error"
super="org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.error"/>
</extension>
```

```java
   public IMarker createMarker(IResource res, int line) throws CoreException {
      if (res != null) {
         IMarker marker = res.createMarker("myproject.ui.error");
         marker.setAttribute(IMarker.PRIORITY, IMarker.PRIORITY_HIGH);
         marker.setAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE, "WrongType");
         marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_START, 0);
         marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_END, 2);
         marker.setAttribute(IMarker.SEVERITY, IMarker.SEVERITY_ERROR);
         return marker;
      }
      return null;
   }
```

Anything missing in the code above?

Comment: You have to call `WorkbenchPart.setTitleImage` with an appropriate image possibly from an `IAnnotationModelListenerExtension` listener on the annotation model. That is what the Java editor appears to do.

Comment: You might need to schedule your marker manipulation within a WorkspaceJob or an IWorkspaceRunnable for the necessary resource deltas to be fired. It's good practice to also include a line number for the Views to use.

Comment: I just test it now, but the current image was overwritten by the error decorator. I want to have both.